# USB SUSPEND MODE

Tags: usb, suspend

Every single guide I read about USB suspend specifies that after HOST stops sending SOF keep alive tokens and after 3ms of IDLE USB device would enter SUSPEND.

Do anyone know cases where HOST stops sending SOF tokens and lets device go into SUSPend mode outside entering Modern Standby?